# Will reused yeast change beer taste?

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters, reusing-yeast

I noticed that some breweries and home brewers reuse yeast for next batch.

But from what I read about yeast mutation and generations that every new cell generation is bit different and can affect beer taste, so how home brewers and breweries reuse yeast and get consistent result?

Also how about yeast starters? as whenever you grow cell count you producing new cells so new cells must be altered as they mutated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

we can get away with re-using yeast, because Mutation isn't instantaneous, it take multiple generations to change a whole batches properties. Also bigger brewers use a "mother culture" to grow more yeast, like making a starters from the same beginning yeast over and over.

In my own experience, i have used the same yeast batch for 3-4 times with no changes to its characteristics one exception was a cream ale blend with a lager yeast and ale yeast, after 2 batches the balance of yeast changed the profile.

EDIT:

> In general, the mutation rate in unicellular eukaryotes (and bacteria) is roughly 0.003 mutations per genome per cell generation

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_rate#cite_note-Genetics-10)